# Is there a way to copy node_modules instead of installing them for create-react-app every time?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules, create-react-app

I am a beginner to React and I am trying to build simple apps by following tutorials to get familiar with React. However, it always bugs me that I have to *download the **node_modules** every time* I create a new react app using

```
create-react-app
```

Is there a way to either,

1. **Opt out of auto-downloading node_modules** when creating a new app using create-react-app, and after the app's basic files have been initiated by **create-react-app** process, **then copy the node_modules directory** into the react app's directory

or

2. Create a **new directory** which has same name as the app, **copy the node_modules directory** into that directory, then run **create-react-app** command(This one seems less possible)

I am still trying to understand the file structure of React and I often misplace files, therefore I often have to start afresh. I am on a *metered internet connection* therefore I cannot afford to download the same set of files every time I start a new app. I do understand that not all the modules are downloaded when creating an app and I am talking about the mandatory packages that I have to download again and again.

Answer (score 0):

You can install modules from the cache. Please, [refer to this post](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2568#issuecomment-331753223) for more detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tools like [Codesandbox](http://codesandbox.io/) for learning purposes. Basic react template is provided over there and you can add additional libraries with a single click.